# Create an array from Image

Tags: c, imagemagick

I have an image (taken from my cell phone camera or maybe drawn in paint on my pc) in which I have white background and drawn lines inside a rectangular figure. I am only considered about the stuff inside the rectangle including it's boundary.

Now I want to create an array out of this such that for all the lines the array should have value 1 and for all the free space array should have 0.

I am working on ubuntu and once the array's been created, I use it further in my C program.

Any leads on what software can I use for this? I heard about imagemagick, will that be helpful?

Kindly help. 
Thanks.

Comment: In which format is your image stored? Is it `YUV` or `RGB` or `JPEG`? If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a negative of the image? Is this a correct understanding?

Comment: I am not sure what negative would imply, but for all the white space inside the rectangular area, the array should have 0 and for all the drawn lines, it should have 1.
I think if I capture it from my camera, it would be JPEG.

Comment: If your image have the only one format (for example, png with fixed parameters) it would be simpler to use single specific library (in that case - libpng), than to use imagemagic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow those steps:

- **Load** image (whatever format) with an image processing library. I propose [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/) as an easy-to-use library.
- Apply **threshold** image and create a b&w version. Here there can be some noise and you may have to play with the threshold value.
- **Detect the large rectangle** (this is somewhat tricky) and **crop** its inside.

Now converting to an array should be easy, just be iterating the pixels and checking if it's black or white.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have until now worked with C language only. I am not sure how to use the Clmg library. Can you tell me what methods shall I use for loading, applying threshold and detect the large rectangle using that library. Or will the link you attached along, will be able to guide me through? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, it's C++ and it might be not not that easy for you.
I haven't used it for a couple of years but I remember it was one of the simplest to use, plus it's only one header file. Check the [tutorial](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks. Once I get the array with 0s and 1s from this method, I will be able to use that in my C program?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You need to code/compile in C++ to use this library. If you you convert to to a C array you can still handle it with your C code.